# Changing a cell's color based on the content in multiple cells in the same ROW

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Example: Cell A1 will be **colorless** if

- the value of B1 is less than 1.49,
- cell C1 does not contain "H"
- AND D1 does not contain "SB".

Cell A1 will turn a **light shade of green** if any one of the following is true:

- B1 contains a value of 1.5 or greater
- or C1 contains "H"
- or D1 contains "SB".

Cell A1 will turn a **darker shade of green** if any two of the following are true:

- B1 contains a value of 1.5 or greater,
- C1 contains "H"
- or D1 contains "SB"

Cell A1 will turn **dark green** if all three conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

add these coloring rules to ur worksheet in this order:

```
=AND($B1>=1,5; $C1="H"; $D1="SB")
=AND($B1<1,5; $C1<>"H"; $D1<>"SB")
=AND($B1>=1,5; OR($C1="H"; $D1="SB"))
=OR($B1>=1,5; $C1="H"; $D1="SB")
```

with the resepctive fill colors in this order:

1. dark
2. white
3. darker/middle
4. light

the "applies to" area must start in a1

**note**

- u can also skip the cond. for white, if that is ur background color anyhow
- i assumed that for white u meant that teh value must be <1.5 and not <1.49 for otherwise u would have a gap for numbers between that range

Comment: Elonderin, I greatly appreciate your interest in my conditional formatting issue. When I use the, "New Rules> Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option I receive an error message suggesting I place an apostrophe in front of the formula. Odd, I thought since this would render the formula useless. Is there something I not doing correctly?

Comment: @ncborn that's odd. which version are u using ? i have just did it with 2010 with both, UI in EN and DE and that worked like a charm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCleo.png.

Comment: @ncborn Did u by chance paste a whitespace somewhere? try also just typing the formula -- F2 is ur friend here to get into edit mode

Answer (score 0):

I have tried typing the formula directly into the Conditional Formatting dialog with the same result. I'm using Microsoft excel 2010.